# move first word to the end of the sentence?

Tags: java, string

Here is SS of the whole question. http://prntscr.com/1dkn2e
it should work with any sentence not just the one given in the example
I know it has to do something with strings. Our professor has gone over with these string methods 
http://prntscr.com/1dknco

This is only a basic java class so don't use any complicated stuff
here is what I have, don't know what to do after this
any help would be appreciated.

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);    
      System.out.println("Enter a line of text. No punctuaton please");
      String sentence = keyboard.nextLine();
      System.out.println(sentence);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as it seem your looking for very simple string arithmetic.
So that's the simplest i could do:

```
      // get the index of the start of the second word
      int index = line.indexOf (' ');
      // get the first char of the second word
      char c = line.charAt(index+1);
      /* this is a bit ugly, yet necessary in order to convert the
       * first char to upper case */
      String start = String.valueOf(c).toUpperCase(); 
      // adding the rest of the sentence
      start += line.substring (index+2);
      // adding space to this string because we cut it
      start += " ";
      // getting the first word of the setence
      String end = line.substring (0 , index);
      // print the string
      System.out.println(start  + end);
```

Comment: code kind of work, the word is replaced instead of th eoriginal 
java is the language
Is thejava java

Comment: Check yourself again, I have tested it, and did it again now. "Is the language java" is my output

Comment: :P i don't see any option to choose this as the answer :S
where is it?
nvm

Answer (score 2):

You can use [public String[] split(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
splitted = sentence.split("\\s+");
```

- `splitted[0]` Is the first word.
- `splitted[splitted.length - 1]` Is the last word.

---

Since your'e not allowed to use `String#split`, you can do this trick:

```
myString = myString.substring(0, myString.lastIndexOf(" ")) + firstWord;
```

By doing this,  you'll have a [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) which contains the sentence without the last word. (For extracting the first word, you can use [String#indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int,%20int%29).

`firstWord` is the first word you extracted before (I'll not solve the whole problem for you, try to do it by yourself, it should be easy now)

Comment: not sure what you mean. And that method is not here http://prntscr.com/1dknco
can you incorporate that code into mine?

Comment: myString = myString.substring(0, myString.lastIndexOf(" ")) + firstWord;
firstWord in eclipse is an error and not sure what you mean by String#indexOf.
maybe we are suppose to do it the way you showed last time . I think our professor just forgot to show us that method
remember i am just a beginner, we had only two classes as of now so I am still confused.

Comment: firstWord yields ofc an error because im sure you havent declared it. The author already mentioned how you can retrieve it. Though he didnt want to provide you with the answere, I will: `String firstWord = myString.substring(0, myString.indexOf(" "))`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String str = "Java is the language";
String first = str.split(" ")[0];
str = str.replace(first, "").trim();
str = str + " " + first;
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: NOTE he asked that the first new char at the start of sentace would be capital letter.

Answer (score -1):

Here is Another way you can do this.
UPDATED: Without Loops

```
              Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);    
      System.out.println("Enter a line of text. No punctuaton please");
      String sentence = keyboard.nextLine();
      System.out.println(sentence);
      int spacePosition = sentence.indexOf(" ");
      String firstString = sentence.substring(0, spacePosition).trim();
      String restOfSentence = sentence.substring(spacePosition, sentence.length()).trim();
      String firstChar = restOfSentence.substring(0, 1);
      firstChar = firstChar.toUpperCase();
      restOfSentence = firstChar + restOfSentence.substring(1, restOfSentence.length());
      System.out.println(restOfSentence + " " + firstString);
      keyboard.close();
```

Comment: I would consider this very bad code. I wouldnt ever show something like this to a beginner.

Comment: I think this is a beginners code, its just basic loops, i dont consider this any advanced level code. Different people different opinion i would say.

Comment: Its kind of complicated though and if one really wants to use loops one can simplify that example alot. E.g `if (sentence.charAt(i) == ' ') firstWord = sentence.substring(0,i);`

Comment: substring() and charAt() is what he can use thats one of the reason its there